# Run a script (not a module) with ghc

Tags: haskell, ghc

Previously I used `ghc` version `< 8` on Linux and when I had a script in a file, say `file.hs`, like

```
let x = "hello"
putStrLn x
double x=2*x
print $ double 2
double 3
```

then it was possible to run it and get the outputs in a terminal by doing

```
ghc -e ':script file.hs'
```

Now I'm using `ghc 8.0.1` on Windows and this does not work anymore. Is there another way ?

I can get the outputs if I open `GHCi` and type `:script file.hs`. But I want these outputs in the terminal.

I don't know whether this is due to the upgrade of `ghc` or to the OS.

Comment: You can use Stack to do it: https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#script-interpreter

Comment: @Sibi `stack file.hs` does not work. If I understand well, it requires some options at the first line of the file. And the example in your link is rather a  "module", no ?

Comment: `ghc -e` works for me on GHC 8.0.1.20161117, with the exact command copied from here

Comment: Yeah, for the script interpreter to work - there should be a `main` function IIRC.

Comment: @CharlieHarding Thank you for the test. It works with my file example ? On Windows ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I ran it on mac, by pasting the example code into a file, then calling `ghc -e ':script file.hs'`. This returned

`hello`
`4`
`6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with double quotes:

```
ghc -e ":script file.hs"
```

Comment: The type of quotes used should make absolutely no difference here.

Comment: @chepner It does, on Windows.

Comment: @chepner Should I take a screenshot of my terminal in order that you remove your downvote ?..

Comment: You should mention that you are using Windows in the question.

Comment: @chepner Indeed, I have not finished a sentence : "Now I'm using ghc 8.0.1 *on Windows*". I thought I had... That's why I mentioned a different OS in my question. I correct, thank you.