# WinGHCi not running on Windows 7

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

I'm very new to Haskell programming language.

I've installed a Haskell platform 8.0.2 on Windows 7: WinGHCi, but it's not running.

I can install and run GHCi, but NOT WinGHCi.

Comment: What does it mean "not running"?

Comment: @Igor When I run it, it says "not responding" on the top bar, and nothing happens if I leave it for hours. I tried to un-install and re-install it again, but it was the same.

Comment: For me it works but honestly it's not terrible. I prefer the "normal" GHCi. It's not worth spending your time for that (unless that's me who has not found how to use it correctly).

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Tell me please how to do the following: I want to write some lines of code in a (text) file. So I can store them. Then, I want to run them in GHCi.

Comment: Save your text file with extension .hs. Double click on the file icon, and WinGHCi should open it

Comment: @user4564798 You want that https://stackoverflow.com/q/41313467/1100107 ?

Comment: @user4564798 Thanks, but it's not running. My GHCi loads Prelude>

Comment: ok, here how I managed to call a file from GHCi  (thanks for your comments and help): I store my code (statring with main=print() ) in a test.hs file. Where test.hs is text file. Then, in GHCi when Prelude> shows up I do the following:    :! ghc test.hs    and then  :load *test.hs          So I can use GHCi and avoid using WinGHCi (as it's still not working).